# DecimalFormat - Format decimal to preserve variable amount of trailing zeros

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I have a situation where I need to preserve the number of decimal places for a number when formatting to a String using DecimalFormat, specifically for trailing zeros. I need to use DecimalFormat because I also need to avoid scientific notation for large numbers, and as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java/25307973#25307973), this is the best way to do so. However, as you can see in that post, the code provided also removes trailing zeros, whereas I would like to preserve them.

```
1.00 -> "1.00"
1.000 -> "1.000"
```

I've seen a lot of questions that involve a fixed number of decimal places, but in my situation I need to account for a variable amount of decimal places. I looked into counting the number of decimal places, but since my input can also be a Double (in addition to BigDecimal), there appears to be no reliable way to count the digits after the decimal point for all numbers. Double.toString() does not work since Doubles break into exponential notation for very small and very big numbers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334168/how-many-decimal-places-in-a-double-java) for more info regarding why it is difficult to count the number of decimal places in a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Preserve" trailing zeros?

A **`double`** value doesn't know how many trailing zeroes you want to see. It is just a *number*, and `1.00` and `1.000` are the same number, i.e. the number `1`. What you are asking **cannot be done with a `double`** value.

Now, **`BigDecimal`** does remember the number of trailing zeroes, so if you want to print a `BigDecimal` value, retaining the scale of the number, but ensuring it never prints in scientific notation, don't use a `DecimalFormat`, but instead **use `toPlainString()`**:

> Returns a string representation of this `BigDecimal` **without an exponent field**.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to print a `double` value with as many decimal fraction digits as needed (i.e. no trailing zeroes), and want to make sure it never prints in scientific notation, use a `DecimalFormat` with very high `MaximumIntegerDigits` and very high `setMaximumFractionDigits`.

"Very high" means values exceeding the range of a `double`, so `999` is a good "round" number, though `330` would be high enough.

*Test*

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0");
fmt.setMaximumIntegerDigits(330);
fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(330);

System.out.println("0.0123400  = " + 0.0123400               + "   = " + fmt.format(0.0123400));
System.out.println("123400.00  = " + 123400.00                + "  = " + fmt.format(123400.00));
System.out.println("NaN        = " + Double.NaN          + "       = " + fmt.format(Double.NaN));
System.out.println("-INFINITY  = " + Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY  + " = " + fmt.format(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
System.out.println("+INFINITY  = " + Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY + "  = " + fmt.format(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
System.out.println("MIN_NORMAL = " + Double.MIN_NORMAL               + " = " + fmt.format(Double.MIN_NORMAL));
System.out.println("MIN_VALUE  = " + Double.MIN_VALUE + "                = " + fmt.format(Double.MIN_VALUE));
System.out.println("MAX_VALUE  = " + Double.MAX_VALUE               + "  = " + fmt.format(Double.MAX_VALUE));
```

*Output*

```
0.0123400  = 0.01234   = 0.01234
123400.00  = 123400.0  = 123400
NaN        = NaN       = �
-INFINITY  = -Infinity = -∞
+INFINITY  = Infinity  = ∞
MIN_NORMAL = 2.2250738585072014E-308 = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022250738585072014
MIN_VALUE  = 4.9E-324                = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000049
MAX_VALUE  = 1.7976931348623157E308  = 179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the input can be a double as well. So if I tried the BigDecimal approach that you outlined with the value 1.2 here is the output:
new BigDecimal(1.2).toPlainString() results in 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875'

Comment: @adiadi Don't use the [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) constructor. Use [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) instead.   The javadoc even tells you so: *This is generally the preferred way to convert a `double` (or `float`) into a `BigDecimal`, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a `BigDecimal` from the result of using `Double.toString(double)`.*

Comment: actually `1.0`, `1.000` and `1` are technically not the same value when represented in floating point binary such as `double` and `float`.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson `1.0`, `1.000` and `1` are *exactly* the same value in a floating point binary such as `double` and `float`, e.g. as a `float` all three are the bytes `3f 80 00 00`. They are not the same in a `BigDecimal`, but are surely the same as a floating point value.

Answer (score 0):

Either `double` (no precision, always approximating values), or `BigDecimal`.

Use BigDecimal as `new BigDecimal("2.00")` defining the correct scale (precision) of two digits. You can set the scale programmatically.

For database and calculation (like financial) BigDecimal is fine.

The scientific representation on output can be avoided in `BigDecimal.toPlainString()`.

For `double` one could format with

```
s = String.format("%10.2f", 13.5789); // "   13.58"
```

All this is with a decimal point and no thousands separators.

**Internationalized** (localized) software will use a `MessageFormat` with a Locale (explicit or the default platform locale).

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("bg", "BG"));
s = MessageFormat.format("Number: {0, number, #.##}, "
            + "amount: {1, number, currency}",
            42.125, 19.99);
```

Comment: Regarding using BigDecimal: I am unable to determine the correct scale for an input that is a double. In all other cases I can do this, but if it is a double I have no way of doing it because a double, as you said, has an approximate value. 

Say an input comes in as 1.200. I need to convert this to a string. How can I do this using DecimalFormat without hardcoding the scale?

Comment: @adiadi You can't. As a `double` value, `1.200` is *exactly* the same number as `1.2`, which you **already know**, since the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334190/5221149) in the second link in your question have already told you so, so why are you asking?

Comment: Either `new BigDecimal("1.200")` (textual input) or `new BigDecimal(1.2).setScale(3)` (yes programmatic as 1.2 == 1.200).

Comment: @adiadi The problem is nothing to do with the approximate nature of double. Double does not have any bits set aside to remember a number of trailing zeros. 1.0, 1.00, 1.000, ... are all represented as 0x3ff0_0000_0000_0000 in double, with no rounding error.